# Error when Azure Logic Apps Reply to Email in Outlook.com with HTML content

Tags: email, azure, outlook, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure logic apps to auto-reply email using outlook.com connector.

When I use plain text in the reply it works fine like following:
[image]

It works as intended and replies to the new email with the text.

But when I use HTML in the comment it gives error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Is it possible to include HTML in the email reply action for outlook.com in logic apps?

Comment: Could you try again? It should definitely work with html. There was an issue earlier today that affected WestUS region for ~20 minutes that could have affected you (and would exhibit itself in the error you run into)

Comment: Tried again. Still same issue.

Comment: You may need to recreate your connection. To get more detailed information, can you inspect the inputs & outputs of this action? (follow 'Run details' in the monitoring/run view for a particular run; it should open up a blade where you can inspect raw inputs and outputs of each action)

Comment: Have checked those. It works perfectly fine for non-HTML content and HTML content we are trying with is also valid and it works if we use 'Send an Email' option instead of 'Reply to Email'.